# json array is not available in my response, i am trying to save my response in model class using retrofit

Tags: android, firebase, retrofit

i am trying to get the response using retrofit but problem is that there is no Json Array in my response. how can we get data?

```
{
  "BTC": {
    "USD": 7183.56
  },
  "ETH": {
    "USD": 183.3
  }
}
```

i am trying the code. which looks like this,

```
@GET("/urlpath")   
Call<currency> getAllCurrency( Query("api-key") String api-key );
```

And i am using this pojo class;

```
public class currency {

        /**
         * BTC : {"USD":7183.56}
         */

        private BTCBean BTC;

        public BTCBean getBTC() {
            return BTC;
        }

        public void setBTC(BTCBean BTC) {
            this.BTC = BTC;
        }

        public static class BTCBean {
            /**
             * USD : 7183.56
             */

            private double USD;

            public double getUSD() {
                return USD;
            }

            public void setUSD(double USD) {
                this.USD = USD;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful to you. I have used the RoboPOJOGenerator plugin to generate models from your given response.

```
data class ResponseModel(

    @field:SerializedName("BTC")
    val bTC: BTC? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("ETH")
    val eTH: ETH? = null
)
data class BTC(

        @field:SerializedName("USD")
        val uSD: Double? = null
)
data class ETH(

        @field:SerializedName("USD")
        val uSD: Double? = null
)
```

Comment: My Problem is that this response creates seperate class for BTC and then seperate  class for ETH

Answer (score 0):

I think your POJO class must have the 2 keys, you are just adding one of the keys which is `BTC`, try this:

```
public class currency {

        /**
         * BTC : {"USD":7183.56}
         */

        private BTCBean BTC;
        //add this 
        private BTCBean ETH;


        //add all setters and getters for the above 2 fields
        //...........
        //...........

         public static class BTCBean {//keep this as you did it.........}


}
```

Comment: My Problem is that this response creates seperate class for BTC and then seperate  class for ETH

Answer (score 0):

Your Pojo class is like below:

```
public class Currency{

@SerializedName("BTC")
@Expose
private BTC bTC;
@SerializedName("ETH")
@Expose
private ETH eTH;

public BTC getBTC() {
return bTC;
}

public void setBTC(BTC bTC) {
this.bTC = bTC;
}

public ETH getETH() {
return eTH;
}

public void setETH(ETH eTH) {
this.eTH = eTH;
}

public class ETH {

@SerializedName("USD")
@Expose
private Double uSD;

public Double getUSD() {
return uSD;
}

public void setUSD(Double uSD) {
this.uSD = uSD;
}

}

public class BTC {

@SerializedName("USD")
@Expose
private Double uSD;

public Double getUSD() {
return uSD;
}

public void setUSD(Double uSD) {
this.uSD = uSD;
}

}

}
```

Comment: My Problem is that this response creates seperate class for BTC and then seperate  class for ETH

Comment: What is actually you want please describe it in details

Comment: In my response there are two JSON object so you make this type of class, what happens if your json object is dynamic means that is coming from service. How can we make the class of each json object

Comment: so your response must be like a list of objects.

Comment: then after you can get an object one by one